# Xubuntu 13.10 64bit - Slow and buggy "log out" process?

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, xfce, ssd, bug-reporting

I'm a Windows convert who has done only a little bit of dabbling in Ubuntu in the past (back in Dapper Drake a few years back). A lot has changes since then, and I've been yearning to jump back into linux again! So, having just bought a new SSD, I felt that this would be as good of a time as any to set up a dual-boot system again. I've messed around with Ubuntu 13.10 a bit, and while Unity has its issues, I think that it still needs some time to develop. I looked into XFCE and liked it a lot, so I went with Xubuntu.

I've installed Xubuntu, and for the most part it's running smoothly and it a pleasure to work with. The customization is great and the minimalistic look and feel is really nice!

But *here's my problem*, whenever I select the "Log Out" option from either the application menu, or the user profiles menu, my PC comes to a crawl, and the dialog box with all the options (shut down, restart, log out, etc.) takes maybe a minute or more to appear. I click the log out button, my PC is brought to a snail's pace, and I have to wait for what seems like an eternity for the logout options to appear! If i try to open something else (even a terminal window) while it's loading the logout options, that other program won't finish loading until the logout screen finally appears.

Keep in mind, this is a pretty much vanilla install of **Xubuntu 13.10 64bit**, on a PC with an **intel i7**, an **SSD**, **6gb DDR3** RAM, and a new **AMD 7770** gpu (drivers haven't been installed yet, though). Everything else runs fast, most applications open near-instantly! It must be an issue with how the logout options screen initializes or something, but I'm not sure exactly how I can fix it..

**Edit - Extra Info:** This problem is very consistent when using the "Log Out" buttons in Xubuntu. However, I've found that I'm able to reboot and shutdown much more quickly by going through the "Switch User" screen, and using the reboot or shutdown buttons on that screen. I'm nearly certain that it has something to do with the little Log Out options screen that appears when I select Log Out from the menu, and not the actual process of shutting down..

So what should I do? I really like XFCE so far, and I've never tried a non-ubuntu based distro before, but should I just switch to something else? Is there any known fix for this issue? Are there any work-arounds for logging out/shutting down/rebooting via the terminal so that I can avoid this irritating bug? Is there any that I can monitor the progress of the log out via terminal, allowing me to see which parts are causing the slow-down? What is the best way to report this bug to someone?

Comment: I don't think it's a xubuntu specific problem, it's the same in ubuntu unity.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone... This is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/1227212) and I must add a VERY annoying bug.

In theory it has been fixed by late 2013 but at least in my case, even after update/upgrade my box was still displaying the same behaviour.

In my case the only way of fixing it was to follow the work-around [documented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/1227212/comments/2) under the same bug:

Comment `xubuntu` in `/etc/upstart-xsessions` and **voilà!**

Answer (score 0):

Try ctl+alt+F2 and switch back with ctrl+alt+F7, the menu magicaly apears.
At least this is how i do it. It has to be a bug of somekind.
If I dont do this combination, i cant interact with any open window, no alt tabin, nothing works. It seems as it froze but it actualy didnt.
I hope it helps, but its a lame circumvention i know.